# Broken link for IBMRestServlet class - RESTFul web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, websphere, rad

I am trying to create my First RESTFul web service with the help of this [site](http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2011/05/22/creating-a-hello-world-restful-web-service-with-rad-and-websphere-application-server-using-ibm-jax-rs/)

But I am getting `Broken Link: com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet`
I searched, to download `com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server` package but I did not found any where.

I am using `Rational Application Developer 7.5.0 and WebSphere Application Server v7.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception means that your application doesn't have this class in `CLASSPATH`.
Probably you have to install additional Feature pack for WebSphere Application Server - `Feature Pack for Web 2.0`.

This is the link to [Getting started with IBM JAX-RS](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.web20fepjaxrs.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_jaxrs_getstarted.html).

You can download [Feature pack from IBM portal](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/web2mobile).

Comment: Actually I did not find jar that contain this class. From where I can get this JAR.

Comment: Do you have installed Feature Pack for Web 2.0?

Comment: Yes, for WebSphere 7.0, you need to install that Feature Pack on top of WebSphere.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I am new to WebSphere, from where I can get Feature Pack for Web 2.0